# Mongo Aggregate Query to get the nested output

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I'm trying with the mongo aggregate query by joining 3 different collections name **department**, **electives** and **students**. Kindly find the sample data for the collections below,

**Department**

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('243s22ca4ff32423ef34'),
  departmentName : "Computer Science",
  headOfDepartment : "243s22ca4ff32423ef12"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**electives**

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('243s22ca4ff32423ef25'),
  electiveName : "Basics of OOPs",
  departmentId : "243s22ca4ff32423ef34"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

**students**

```
{
  _id : ObjectId('243s22ca4ff32423ef37'),
  studentName : "Raghu",
  electiveId : "243s22ca4ff32423ef25"
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I'm trying to build the aggregate query by applying filter based on the department to get the sample output like below,

```
{
  departmentName : "Computer Science",
  headOfDepartment : "243s22ca4ff32423ef12",
  electivesList : [
  {
     electiveId : "243s22ca4ff32423ef25",
     electiveName : "Basics of OOPs",
     studentsCount : 20,
     studentsList : [
     {
        studentId : "243s22ca4ff32423ef37",
        studentName : "Raghu",
     }
     ]
  }
  ]
}
```

I'm currently stuck with the lookup of the 2nd collection(electives) with the 3rd collection(students). Kindly provide some guidance.

Comment: 1. Show what you have tried. 2. Your ObjectIDs are invalid, there can't be an 's' and the length is incorrect. 3. Is the `departmentId` & `electiveId` stored as a string as shown or as an ObjectID?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $lookup at root level and inside of it too but as @aneroid said your ObjectId is not valid and as well it is a string, that why I convert _id to string, the use of $expr is required to access the variable

> A $match stage requires the use of an $expr operator to access the variables. The $expr operator allows the use of aggregation expressions inside of the $match syntax.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

```
[
  {
    $lookup:
      {
        from: "electives",
        let: {
          id: {
            $toString: "$_id",
          },
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ["$departmentId", "$$id"],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "students",
              let: {
                id2: {
                  $toString: "$_id",
                },
              },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$electiveId",
                        "$$id2",
                      ],
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "studentsList",
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "electivesList",
      },
  },
]
```